# Parse a date json To DateTime

Tags: c#, json

**The JSON is:**

```json
{"date":13,"day":5,"hours":19,"minutes":6,"month":10,"nanos":0,"seconds":41,"time":1605265601000,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":120}
```

**When I try to Convert to `DateTime`, I encountered the following error:**

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
> Source=Newtonsoft.Json
> StackTrace:
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsDateTime()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
> at test.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\code\UI\test\Program.cs:line 77

**My Code:**

```cs
var txt = "{\"date\":13,\"day\":5,\"hours\":19,\"minutes\":6,\"month\":10,\"nanos\":0,\"seconds\":41,\"time\":1605265601000,\"timezoneOffset\":-480,\"year\":120}";
var aa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(txt);
Console.ReadKey();
```

when I use Newtonsoft.Json.dll 3.5 version instead, the error disappears.
when I use Newtonsoft.Json.dll 9.0 version instead, the error appears.

I'm using VS2017 to Build, where is my Error?

Comment: It's searching for ```saleTime``` property which does not exist in ```DateTime```

Comment: I think you should create a corresponding class of your JSON txt and deserialize to your class and expose the saleTime by using a method.

Comment: I'm sorry for this error,and edited question again,the saleTime removed

Comment: by don't remove `saleTime` text, I'm also try to create a class by DateTime property,like this `public class DateTest
    {
        public DateTime saleTime { get; set; }
    }`, and deserialize code modify to this : ` var aa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTest>(txt); `, the error also exists

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Json.NET now expects `DateTime` values to be represented as strings, rather than as JSON objects. Certainly the representation you've got is an unusual one. I suggest you create your own class that follows the JSON, and write a `ToDateTime` (or better `ToDateTimeOffset`) to convert it.

(I'm really surprised that earlier versions of Json.NET could handle this at all.)

Better yet, if you're in control of the code that's *creating* this JSON, ideally change it to a more sensible format, e.g. an ISO-8601 string.

Here's an example of code to perform the conversion. The offset handling is a little odd, due to a mixture of the way `DateTimeOffset` works and the way the offset appears to be expressed :(

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var txt = "{\"date\":13,\"day\":5,\"hours\":19,\"minutes\":6,\"month\":10,\"nanos\":0,\"seconds\":41,\"time\":1605265601000,\"timezoneOffset\":-480,\"year\":120}";
        var jdto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDateTimeOffset>(txt);
        var dto = jdto.ToDateTimeOffset();
        Console.WriteLine(dto);
        Console.WriteLine(dto.ToUniversalTime());
    }
}

public class JsonDateTimeOffset
{
    // All ignored as the Time property handles all these.
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
    // Ignored, as we don't know what it means.
    public int Nanos { get; set; }
    
    // Milliseconds since the unix epoch
    public long Time { get; set; }
    
    // UTC offset in minutes, but reversed from the normal
    // view.
    [JsonProperty("timezoneOffset")]
    public int TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
    
    public DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset()
    {
        var instant = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Time);
        var offset = -TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeZoneOffset);
        return new DateTimeOffset(instant.DateTime + offset, offset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deserialised object is actually

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int hours { get; set; }
    public int minutes { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int nanos { get; set; }
    public int seconds { get; set; }
    public long time { get; set; }
    public int timezoneOffset { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}
```

and you cannot deserialize this class directly to DateTime.

Now two options come to my mind.
Use an [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) or create a new `DateTime` instance from the properties of the `RootObject` class.

Comment: "More specifically the backslashes seem to break the integrity." - the OP's JSON doesn't contain any backslashes. The string literal does, but the JSON doesn't - try using the OP's first line of code and then write `Console.WriteLine(txt);`. You'll see there are no backslashes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for pointing that out! I ll grab another cup of coffee